# What is the proper structure to save and work with dates with JS?

Tags: database, mongodb, date, timestamp

If I print `new Date()` I will receive the date and the hour based on a specific timezome.

And timezones are not the same :)

That means that the output will be different from different places.

I thought about this structure for saving dates in DB:

```
{
  date: {
    text: "08-10-2018",
    timestamp: THE_TIME_STAMP
  }
}
```

And then convert timestamp to date and time.

I don't want every user will see the creation date of the creator timezone - I want each user to see the creation date based on his own timezome.

My question is what should I save in the DB?
Should I use timestamp instead?
Timestamp will be matched to the user's timezone?
What is the best practice in here?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't store the date/time in string. That's always a bad idea.**

MongoDB has a built-in Date type, that its drivers support. It will store the date in `ISODate` format. If you have a nodejs backend, you just have to supply the JS date object, and the driver will handle everything.

You can query the data for a range of dates, that you cannot do properly if you store it as a string.

You can convert the UTC ISODate to the viewer's timezone on your frontend.

If you have a js based frontend, you can use [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or moment.js to convert to different timezones.

Comment: If i want to grab just the hour and minute (time) of post creation, which is saved with new Date() via JS, how could I retrieve this? And this will be the right hour and minute based on reader's timezone?

Comment: @Raz, No, what I'm telling you is you grab the UTC date from database, and then convert it on frontend. There are lots of libraries which can help you with that as mentioned in the last line of my answer. Check the library's page, you will get some examples